# Angular2 RxJS why doesn't map() work?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Angular2 http requests return observables.  In the documentation for observables, you can use the function `.map()` on an observable.

But when I use `.map()` on my http observable I get this error:

```
argument is not a function. Are you looking for `mapTo()`?
```

`.mapTo()` seems to provide somewhat similar behavior, but I'm wondering.... why doesn't `.map()` work here?

EDIT:

Thanks, here is a bit more information.  I am using webpack and Angular 2.0.0-beta.8.

The abbreviated actual code looks like:

```
  import { Observable, map, concatMap, flatMap, reduce, subscribe } from 'rxjs';

  getRequest(endpoint) {
    return this.http.get('https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/' + endpoint,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' +
          localStorage.getItem(this.name + 'AccessToken'),
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).map(response => response.json());
  }

  var profileRequest = this.getRequest('profile.json');
  var profileRequestLog = profileRequest.map('profile fetched');
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to this, so not sure if I can help. Can you post a sample of how you made your http request, and also maybe what version of angular 2 you're using?

Comment: You can use `.map()` on an observable IF you've properly included RxJS.  Have you done so?  Are you sure it's loaded and mapped correctly?  Showing your code and your module configuration would make it much more likely that we could point you in the right direction.

Comment: Could you please add some code?

Answer (score 3):

please make sure following `Rx.min.js` file is included in `index.html`.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.9/Rx.min.js">
</script> //CDN reference
```

Then you can import followings to work with `Observable` and its `operators`

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Comment: I have included a bunch of imports, but should all those imports be necessary?  Shouldn't angular2 include relevant RxJS functions, such as `map()`?

Comment: Yes rxjs will add it but you have to follow my way. Import rxjs/Rx will import all rx operators. Note it if u do it, u dont need to call/ import individual operator.